# Using CTRL-W_f / gf on `file.name://`

Tags: file

A common action I perform in Vim is to do `$ grep` or `$ git grep` (in a vim `:terminal`), and then open the files discovered.

This works great most of the time. However, I noticed that considering the following output from grep/git grep:

```
my-file:    some code
my-file:// my comments
my-file:/ test
my-file:/// test
```

The first line will work properly with Vim `gf` and the like, so we know that vim is ignoring the colon as expected.Similarly, the third line also works.

However, the second and fourth line don't work, with vim reporting `E447: Can't find file "my-file://" in path`.

It seems that with two or more slashes after the colon, `gf` no longer works as expected. This suggests that Vim is parsing the text as a URL? I don't think I have ever or will ever find a use for URLs and `gf`.

My `isfname` does not contain the `:` character.

What is causing Vim to behave unexpectedly for `gf`, and how do I make it behave the way I expect it to?

Comment: Could you tell us what is the value returned by `:set includeexpr?` and by: `:set ft?`?

Comment: @VivianDeSmedt `:set includeexpr?` gives an empty `includeexpr=`. As mentioned, I call this from the vim terminal, which likewise gives for `:set ft?`  an empty value `filetype=`.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I'll try to reproduce the problem at my end.

Comment: I can reproduce the problem on my end :-)

Comment: FWIW, using Vim's `:help :grep`in combination with `:help quickfix` seems more efficient than your current strategy.

Comment: @romainl I read it once in the manual and didn't understand it then (never understood the meaning of quickfix). I guess I should reread it sometime...

Comment: You should, yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve the problem by setting the `includeexpr` option to the following value:

```
set includeexpr=substitute(v:fname,'\\(^[^:]*\\).*','\\1','')
```

But the mystery about why this is needed in case `:` is not part of `isfname` remains.

Comment: I discovered that this fixes CTRL-W_f but apparently doesn't fix gf...